# C# & LinkedIn: authenticate user from desktop application?

Tags: c#, wpf, linkedin-api

I have to authenticate a LinkedIn user from within a desktop app (WPF).

The official guide [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) suggests to:

> redirect user to LinkedIn's authorization dialog

(in a context of a web application, obviously)

But how exactly do I solve this within a desktop app?

Do I open the clients browser and redirect the user to the link?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: have you managed this question? I see that it has an accepted answer, but those links doesn't help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out these links:

[LinkedIn Developer Help](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1190)

[Wordpress Post](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/dotnetopenauth-oauth-and-mvc-for-dummies/)

[LinkedIn Toolkit help](http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/)

[Linkedin Windows Client](https://github.com/fyasar/LinkedIn-Windows-Client)

Comment: But all of these examples use asp.net - was there already. Can you provide some insight on how I would modify, for example, the public ActionResult StartOAuth() function from the Wordpress link so it would work inside a desktop app?

Comment: Added another URL for windows client. You can use similar approach for WPF too.

Comment: Have you tried the application? I entered my API/Secret key, clicked "Create authorization" and "Authorize", but the "Get Access Token" button doesn't get enabled after that. Any idea why? Does the app work for you?

Comment: I have not done this for long time now. I remember doing something similar sometime back. Are you getting any error response back?